# Is asking users to waive GDPR compliance a legal way of escaping GDPR data handling requirements?

Tags: gdpr, european-union, terms-of-service

I have recently come across this part of an app from a well-known US company:

[image]

Is this a legal way of handling some of the technical obstacles GDPR introduced? Is this a "flexible" interpretation of the law or is it straight up illegal?

To give the whole picture - I was asked where I live and based on that I was presented with this consent sheet. If I don't check the box, I cannot move any further - I have to give consent if I want to use the app.

I was OK with giving that consent, but does that mean I also lose my rights that come with GDPR? The right to download my data, the right to be forgotten etc?

I'm not interested in shaming the company, but I am interested in knowing if the approach - *"I'll ask if they are OK with losing those rights so that I can do whatever I want"* - is a correct way of handling the law. I didn't assume GDPR is "optional". Kind of defeats the purpose of having it if companies can put this in the fine print or worse - disallow anybody to use their software unless they give their private data to them with no strings attached.

I saw and read a connected question [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28856/is-requesting-waiving-the-right-to-deletion-of-contributions-against-gdpr/28858#28858), but in my situation, I am actually **unable** to do anything **unless** I accept the terms.

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about their compliance with GDPR, or lack thereof. Asking whether you consent to your data being processed outside the EU is orthogonal to them being subject to GDPR by virtue of them serving a EU citizen.

Comment: While the GDPR protections can't be waived, as the answers state, it's reasonable for a company to disallow anyone from using their software if the user doesn't give their consent to a required use of their data (as long as the data use and request are legal). The company has a right to not provide service to anyone they choose, as long as it's not for an illegal reason. In fact, it's quite normal and, actually, necessary for a company to refuse to provide service unless they have your consent to use your data. Requiring companies to explicitly get that consent was one of the things GDPR did.

Comment: @Makyen: That's not exactly so simple. The GDPR absolutely requires that consent is _freely_ given, and it appears that withholding the service means the consent is no longer freely given. You're right that the company has the right to do business with whoever they want, but only within the law including the GDPR.

Comment: Were the tick boxes automatically ticked? Because even that is a bit questionable from a GDPR standpoint (consent should be 'opt-in' not 'opt-out')

Comment: @DaveMongoose they were **not** pre-ticked. I've seen such practice elsewhere, but this was not the case.

Comment: @MSalters I think you have a skewed view of what *freely given* means. The company doesn't owe you service. If they were legally mandated to provide you service, then there might be an argument that consent wasn't freely given. The company clearly establishing that they won't begin giving service unless you give consent to their use of your data is part of a typical contractual relationship. The GDPR *doesn't* give you a *right* to *force* them to provide service to you, which is what you are effectively arguing.

Comment: @Makyen I see your point with the right to force a service, but what about the other way around - *right to provide service*? Surely, if they aren't capable of being compliant with the laws, they shouldn't really provide the service in the given region (in this case, the EU). No?

Comment: @Makyen: See also Peteris' answer. The problem with your logic is that the GDPR puts the onus on the company to show freely given consent. That means a dissatisfied user can file a complaint against your company that you illegally processed their data, and you won't be able to defend yourself against that claim.

Comment: @MSalters: _"and you won't be able to defend yourself against that claim"_ But that is **exactly** why consent is asked for - to preclude a claim that the user never agreed to the events that they're now lodging a complaint about. Anyone who uses the service must have consented to what the service entails. That is by design specifically to defend against such claims.

Comment: @MSalters We appear to be talking past each other. Your earlier comment appears to ignore that I said that that they can decline service if the potential customer "doesn't give their consent to a *required* use of their data". Ignoring that I qualified the consent as to a *required* use appears to have resulted in this going off on a tangent. There also appears to be confusion as to if we're talking about this specific case, or generalities. As to this specific case, the company appears to not be in compliance with GDPR in multiple ways, and *probably* isn't in compliance in additional ways.

Comment: @Michal Yes the smart/correct thing to do if they can't be, or choose not to be, compliant with GDPR is to not provide the service in an area/to anyone where they would need to be in compliance with GDPR. Unfortunately, it's quite common for people/companies to not to the smart/reasonable thing.

Comment: @Makyen: I'm ignoring the _required_ because it doesn't make sense. If it's legally required, the GDPR doesn't demand consent. If it's "required" because of an arbitrary company policy saying so, that's just the company saying so. And then the company has the problem that the GDPR puts the choice not with the company but with the consumer. In the end, the GDPR has only 6 justified grounds, and you cannot invent another. "Consent or no service" just isn't one of those 6.

Comment: @Makyen "The company has a right to not provide service to anyone they choose, as long as it's not for an illegal reason." You're straying into complex territory there, and it's likely to vary by jurisdiction. Most countries have anti-discrimination laws. And in the UK (I'm told) you can sue if the supplier has abused a dominant position contrary to the prohibition imposed by section 18 (the Chapter II prohibition) of the Competition Act 1998.

Comment: @Makyen see https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/lawful-basis-for-processing/consent/ and in particular "If you make consent a precondition of a service, it is unlikely to be the most appropriate lawful basis". If the company *needs* to do those things to provide a service then they don't need separate consent, and if they don't need to do so then making the service conditional on consent is not valid.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103050/discussion-on-question-by-michal-is-asking-users-to-waive-gdpr-compliance-a-lega).

Comment: If the company is a US company, how could the European Union enforce the GPDR? Yes, they could block payments via credit cards or bank transfers, but what if the service is free? Could the EU issue a warrant to have the CEO extradited to face trial?

Answer (score 41):

GDPR does not cease to apply because of the location of data storage.  It applies based on the location of the data processor, data controller, and data subject.  If you are in the EU, you are a data subject covered by GDPR.  It does not matter where the data are stored.

Note that you are asked to confirm that you're aware that US laws may be less protective, but you're not asked to acknowledge that anything about the arrangement causes the "laws of your country/region" not to apply.  The company also does not seem to be claiming that they don't apply, although it seems that they want you to think so, and it's not clear whether they think so.

You are correct that GDPR doesn't allow its protections to be waived.  A data subject may always consent to certain processing, and some processing may be performed without consent, but it's not possible to waive the right to withhold consent for processing that does require it.

Comment: Does GDPR actually have any teeth outside of the EU? I mean, if somebody living in the US creates a US-centric service with no intent of offering services to the EU, surely the company doesn't have any real obligations to obey GDPR if an EU citizen decides to sign up for it? Would a US court uphold EU law in this case? I'm assuming not.

Comment: [Seemingly not](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/28065/14696), if I'm reading it right.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103049/discussion-on-answer-by-phoog-is-asking-users-to-waive-gdpr-compliance-a-legal-w).

Comment: If the company is a US company, how could the European Union enforce the GPDR? Yes, they could block payments via credit cards or bank transfers, but what if the service is free? Could the EU issue a warrant to have the CEO extradited to face trial?

Comment: @Chloe there are some questions here that go into that.  The penalties are civil, however, not criminal, so there would be no extradition.  A foreign civil judgment can be enforced in the US, which is I suppose why some US sites refuse to serve their pages to IP addresses in the EU.  (But small violations would probably not be worth the effort.)  Further discussion in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103049/discussion-on-answer-by-phoog-is-asking-users-to-waive-gdpr-compliance-a-legal-w), please.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica: I think there is a huge difference in between _"run a US company not targetting EU, and not knowing or caring who might use the service"_ on the one hand side, and explicitly asking, and then showing such a consent screen. Which unmistakably demonstrates the _explicit_ intent to do business in the EU (thus making you subject to EU laws whether you like it or not). In the case of _that particular_ US company, they happen to have an office in Ireland... so... they _are_ bound by EU law one way or the other, even if they try to give a fraudulent impression to end users.

Answer (score 27):

### GDPR consent must be freely given

The GDPR conditions for consent define it as (article 4.11) "‘consent’ of the data subject means any freely given, specific, informed and unambiguous indication of the data subject’s wishes by which he or she, by a statement or by a clear affirmative action, signifies agreement to the processing of personal data relating to him or her".  It's worth noting that all the criteria are mandatory - if one of them is missing (e.g. it's not specific or not freely given) then it's not consent according to GDPR.

GDPR article 7.4 states "When assessing whether consent is freely given, utmost account shall be taken of whether, inter alia, the performance of a contract, including the provision of a service, is conditional on consent to the processing of personal data that is not necessary for the performance of that contract."  To clarify this, GDPR recital 43 states "Consent is presumed not to be freely given if [...] the performance of a contract, including the provision of a service, is dependent on the consent despite such consent not being necessary for such performance." which is explicitly about cases like this - if providing the service is conditional on "consenting", then that consent shall be presumed to *not* be freely given, and thus it is *not* valid consent.

Thus, a record that this checkbox was checked does not give the company a legal basis to use your data. In particular, GDPR 7.1 states "Where processing is based on consent, the controller shall be able to demonstrate that the data subject has consented to processing of his or her personal data." , so it's their duty to show that you *actually* consented and your consent fulfills all the criteria, and it appears that they can not. One way to proceed would be to 'agree' to the checkbox, immediately follow up with a GDPR data request (asking them to affirm what legal basis allows them to process the data), and if they list "consent" as the legal basis (they might not, there are other possible ways) then dispute that with your local data protection authority.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the data collection is _not_ essential to the performance of the service, which without knowing the specifics of the service, we cannot determine.

Comment: @asgallant yes, so as suggested, a GDPR data request would reveal their interpretation. However, it does beg the question of why are they asking for consent if they don't need it? The whole fact that they have intentionally added this checkbox suggests that they likely believe that they can't assert that this particular use of data (the fact that collecting data is needed for one legitimate purpose doesn't by itself grant the right to use that data for any other purpose) is legit based on other parts of Article 6.1 and they need some form of consent to qualify under Art 6.1(a).

Comment: How do you know they don't need consent? The claim is that they need to collect and process certain personal data in order to perform the service. That seems to me to meet the criteria for requiring users to give consent. The presence of the checkbox is not automatically a red flag that the company is doing something wrong. You need to know more to make that determination. Ex, if a note taking app required users to consent to collection and processing of GPS data, contacts, etc, in order to use the app, _that_ would be a red flag. (continued)

Comment: A health tracking app that collects heart rate, blood sugar levels, steps taken, etc. that requires consent to collect and process that data in order to use the app is not _necessarily_ a red flag.

Comment: @Peteris Consider a firm which offers email alerts when something interesting happens.  They will require the email address in order to provide the service; and "necessity" will be the legal basis of the data processing.  They are still free to ask a prospective customer if it's OK to store and use the email address; if the answer is "no", then the deal is off - but better that than a pissed-off customer later.  (Yes, this is a rather contrived example, but more realistic ones are possible.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: Storing and using that email address is allowed (as a necessity) for the given purpose, and only that purpose. You may additionally ask for _freely given_ consent for other uses such as advertisements, but you cannot mix the consent use and the necessary use.

Comment: @MSalters My example specifically only involved **one** purpose (which is legally allowed as a necessity).  I am trying to make the (linked) points that a) just because a website operator asks if it is OK to process data does *not* mean that the legal basis for processing that data is going to be freely given consent b) the operator is allowed to ask, even if the legal basis is not consent.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica indeed.  In US criminal law, the fruits of a consensual search are admissible at trial, so a police officer will try to obtain consent so the prosecutor does not have to face the burden of establishing that the search was otherwise justified. A data controller who has the data subject's consent is similarly relieved from the burden of showing that the processing was otherwise justified, but such a justification could certainly exist.  If it does, and the data subject withdraws consent, then the controller can decide whether to face the burden or delete the data.

Answer (score 4):

GDPR puts several requirements on a company to be compliant.

Among these is the requirement to seek informed consent from the data subject, ie. you, to store and use data.

As such the waiver you are asked to agree does not seem to be an attempt to bypass GDPR, but rather explicitly following the letter of the law.

Please note the following;

- You are not being asked to waive any rights regarding a data breach.
- The company is not asking to be allowed to use the data for purposes other than to provide wellness and fitness services.
- The company is not asking to be allowed to store data not needed for it to provide wellness and fitness services
- The company is not asking you to indemnify them if a data processor uses the data for purposes not required to provide you with wellness and fitness services.
- The company explicitly notes that you are free to withdraw consent at a later time.
- You where not asked to give up your right to receive the data.
- You where not asked to give up any rights to have your data be deleted.

Considering that health information is considered sensitive it seems difficult to see how a company could offer "welness and fitness services" in a GDPR compliant manner without a waiver similar to the one you were presented with.

GDPR does put the requirement that the consent be freely given, but "If I do not give the consent I would be unable to use the service" is not usually considered coercion.

In conclusion, there are parts of the GDPR that applies even if the subject has agreed to a waiver (processes surrounding data breaches, not using data for purposes other than what it was provided for, etc.), but nothing in the agreement you are being asked for seems to touch this.

Answer (score 1):

Consent is a lawfuls basis for processing both sensitive data and for transferring data overseas.  Providing consent does not give the data controller the ability to ignore your rights under GDPR, nor is this organisation implying this, so I expect you would have some assurance.

The issue with the solution provided here is that to be lawful under GDPR consent must be 'feeely given'.  If you cannot have the service without consent, then it is not being given freely.  Therefore the organisation is still not undertaking this processing legally.

Comment: "If you cannot have the service without consent, then it is not being given freely": this is incorrect.  In general, a consumer is free to refrain from buying a service.  For consent to be coerced, something more must exist than simply not being able to use a service without consent.

Comment: @phoog Depends on the service, but that's probably true for most services.

Comment: @phoog: Art. 7 GDPR: When assessing whether consent is freely given, utmost account shall be taken of whether, inter alia, the performance of a contract, including the provision of a service, is conditional on consent to the processing of personal data that is not necessary for the performance of that contract.

Comment: @fNek precisely: "...that is not necessary for the performance of that contract" means that the if the data processing *is* necessary for the performance of the contract then that doesn't have any bearing on the determination of whether the consent was freely given, because the data subject is free to refrain from entering into the contract.

Comment: To expand on what @fNek says, knowing your age is probably necessary to providing a wellness and fitness service; knowing your date of birth is not. So (in theory at least) they are not allowed to demand your date of birth, only your age.

Comment: @MichaelKay I understand the point you're making, but this might not be the best example because without knowing your date of birth they won't know when your age changes.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully: some other answers impliedly assume the question engages GDPR issues. *It doesn't*!!!

The correct answer is: "not a snowball's chance in hell". Why? Because the question actually confronts the rule of law which as meta-law, surprise surprise, aborts any other legal issue.

Any agreement between data subjects and controllers is private law. The GDPR is statutory. The proposed waiver falls into a certain category expressed roughly as follows: "**Any private law agreement to usurp the jurisdiction of the Court is void for illegality**".

For the same reason it's unenforceable. So the data subjects can reverse their decision to waive at any time without breaching any "agreement". Because the "agreement" was void ab initio.

For the same reason, of course, any T&C that imports any Privacy Notice [edit: in a way that would conflict with any statute] is likewise void for illegality (or at least the clause is severed if a valid severability clause exists compliant with local contract law severability doctrine).

Here's an illustration. A few months ago some judge, in the backwoods of some unenlightened hick jurisdiction, invented this crazy rule that forming a contract with a hit man to waive the compliance rules on murder and assassinate the [ boss / spouse / driver annoying you at the traffic lights] might risk a polite invitation to Court and another polite invitation to jail, expressed as an offer too good to refuse. Especially if the judge’s football team lost the previous day. So be careful where you strike such deals. And make sure your favourite assassins (and data subject users) don’t snitch on you. Just say please!

Even lawyers fall into this trap, on a metalevel. I've seen too many tech company contracts that include wording such as "the parties agree to waive the Court's domestic rules of private international law". When judges sees such words, they respond in some of three non-exclusive ways: rip into the drafters if they're stupid enough to be present in Court; limit themselves to a shark-like smile while laughing like a drain inside; or maintaining a polite poker face while wondering "how will I resist the temptation of screwing you over for this disrespectful and arrogant attempt to create a potential international incident?".